# How to Refresh Gallery instantly?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gallery

I am using Kitkat 4.4.2 on my android device.

When I mount USB drive to my device then all the images,videos in USB drive are shown in the Gallery. After unmounting USB drive, images,videos are still there as a thumbnails.

Can't I refresh my gallery without rebooting?

Answer (score 9):

The system itself AFAIK doesn't expose a GUI element to do so. However, you have multiple options to trigger the *Media Scanner*:

- Reboot the device (not that convenient)
- unmounting/remounting the SD card (via *Settings*; better, but still not convenient)
- using one of the apps/widgets available in the app stores. One that's reportedly working with Kitkat is [SD Scanner](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sd-scanner/com.gmail.jerickson314.sdscanner) (see [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/71521/16575))
- using ADB to trigger it (telling it the card has just been mounted – so basically we fake the second option):

  ```
  adb shell "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard"
  ```
- **Edit:** Some ROMs (e.g. CyanogenMod) seem to have a GUI element for it in *Settings › Developer options › Developer tools › Media provider* – where you can find a button labeled "SCAN SD CARD"

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to `am force-stop com.android.gallery3d`

Comment: I unmounted/remounted the SD card, then killed the Gallery app and restarted it. The photos have reappeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting - app - gallery force stop and clear cache. Gallery will reload all those media.

Comment: Last time I did this, it worked though some of the thumbnails couldn't be loaded anymore.

Comment: This had no effect for me.